# What is the difference between 夕立 and 朝立ち?

Tags: words

What is the difference between 夕立 and 朝立ち? They both refer to the kanji 立, and have contrastive words 夕 (evening) and 朝 (morning). Are they antonyms, or is there any difference between them?

分かりやすく教えてください。お願いします。

Comment: one is a boner..

Comment: 辞書かウィキで調べてみてはいかがですか。[朝立ち](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%9D%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A1)・[夕立](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%95%E7%AB%8B)

Comment: @ssb:  I will give you all the upvotes if you post that as an answer.

Comment: @Chokoさんに反応されるなんて、はずかしいわ

Comment: @Darius 釣りしか見えないな => 釣りにしか見えないな

Comment: shows no research effort. Easy to answer by consulting a dictionary. Likely to be a trolling question.

Comment: @Darius どう変えれば荒らしに見えなくなりますか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not antonyms. They're very different from each other. 立 on it's own [means](http://www.romajidesu.com/kanji/%E7%AB%8B) to stand up, to erect and stuff like that. When you use this Kanji in a word like in the case of [朝立]{あさだ}ち　which [means](http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E6%9C%9D%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A1.html) early morning erection, you can see how the 立 fits into the word, i.e your manhood being erect.

In the other word [夕立]{ゆうだち} which [means](http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E5%A4%95%E7%AB%8B.html) sudden evening shower/rain, I don't know how the 立 fits in but yeah it's not close to meaning 朝立ち